# How do I add my own compiler flags when using gcc:Config?

Tags: rust

In my build.rs file, I placed the following:

```
extern crate gcc;

fn main() {
    gcc::Config::new().file("src/test.c").compile("libtest.a");
}
```

and it works well. I want to add a couple flags, such as linking to my own library "-lmylib" and maybe "-fPIC".

Comment: Please avoid doing so if *at all* possible.  There's a method for PIC, and you should be able to ask Cargo to link libraries.  Remember that the `gcc` crate isn't *just* for GCC: it also runs `clang` and the Microsoft compiler depending on what's installed (yes, the crate is badly named).  There's little more infuriating than running into a crate that doesn't work on your system *purely* because of some platform-specific detail.  If you **really** need this, OK, but just be sure about that first, and try to provide a fallback where possible.  *Please.*

Comment: Are you trying to link a library to `libtest.a`, or your rust library?

Comment: I'm just trying to link to an external C library.  I'd actually rather not compile it but it works when I compile it (if I don't need a flag).  I can't get it to link otherwise.  I think I'll focus on linking it without compiling, since I'd prefer that anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `gcc::Config` has a function called [flag](http://alexcrichton.com/gcc-rs/gcc/struct.Config.html#method.flag) for arbitrary gcc flags:

```
extern crate gcc;

fn main() {
    gcc::Config::new()
        .file("src/test.c")
        .flag("-lmylib")
        .flag("-fPIC")
        .compile("libtest.a");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually tried that before and it doesn't seem to work.